# Proper throw syntax in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

If I use:

```
throw new Error('You broke it');
```

I get an output in the chrome console that looks like this:
[image: throw new Error()]

where it basically looks like it's doing

```
console.error(new Error('You broke it'))
```

as opposed to

```
console.error('You broke it')
```

whereas if I use

```
throw 'You broke it';
```

I get this:
[image: throw String]

which looks more like what I would expect.

Why does Chrome do this, and which way is correct?

I've always been told to use the first method, but the console output looks sloppier, though when I wrap a `try` `catch`, around the second it passes only the string as opposed to an actual `Error` object.

Included Firefox for reference:
[image]

Comment: In the first case I get `▶︎ Error: You broke it` in Chrome, just like it looks in Firefox. Either way, I guess it depends on what purpose the errors have. If you want that others are able to `catch` errors, you should probably use the constructor version, especially if you have different types of errors. If you just want it for providing a better debugging experience, use whatever floats your boat :)

Comment: I see `console.error` at the beginning of the question, the screen shot shows `console.log`

Comment: The undefined comes from the lack of a return value from the `console.error()` function.

Comment: @FelixKling, You can catch anything thrown, see the FF screenshot. In the case of `throw String()` you `catch` a `String()`, in the case of `throw Error()` you `catch` an `Error()`.

Comment: @JasonSperske the question mentions the difference in appearance, not the method used in the `try catch`, which is as you noticed `console.log()`, and the `undefined` comes from entering anything in the browser console that doesn't have a return value, including the `try catch` block.

Answer (score 1):

You can `throw` any object you want -- that includes strings. So in that sense, there's nothing incorrect with either of your examples. However, you'll usually want to throw an `Error` object, in part because that gives you helpful information such as `err.stack`, etc.